# Converting a bootable USB into an ISO image

Tags: usb, conversion, live-usb, iso

I know how to make a bootable USB, but how does one make an ISO image out of a bootable USB?

Comment: We will need more details, what is the contents of the ISO, specifically the OS and bootloader. If this is MacOS this is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dd to duplicate data across devices. Using conv option you can modify data during transfer

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=myiso.iso
```

Comment: Can't believe I haven't tried that. Thank you.